# No output from GRASS 7 r.reclass in Processing Python script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I want to run the r.reclass tool in python on a raster layer to reclassify 1 value (and leave the rest the way they are).

Here is my best attempt so far, after trying to reference documentation and other examples. Here is my code:

```
import processing

input_raster = QgsRasterLayer('/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Key-LogEcovaluator/Rasters/AestheticMax.tif', 'raster')
output_raster = '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/OutputReclass.tif'
rules_file = '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/reclassrules.txt'


parameters = {'Input' : input_raster,
            'rules' : rules_file,
            'Output' : output_raster,
            'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : '1277290, 1314314, -14004, 11845',   #this is the exent of my raster layer
            'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0
            }

processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:r.reclass', parameters)
```

I run the script and I don't get any errors, but nothing happens. No output, nothing is reclassified. I think I am missing something obvious here.

Here is how I define my reclassification rules. As far as I can tell from [the grass 7 documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html) this is correct:

```
35 = 99
```

Really, I am reclassifying one value (35 = 99).

I get the help docs by running the following in the console:

```
processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:r.reclass")
```

Two of the input parameters are confusing to me. Specifically GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT and GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META. Are these required?

Comment: It looks like you're using the older 2.x API under QGIS 3?

Comment: How did you define your rules in your _rules.txt_ file?

Comment: @Joseph sorry for the slow response.  I edited my question with my rules defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raster type likely cannot hold negative values.

Run gdalinfo on AestheticMax.tif and you will likely find it is 8-bit integer.

So the answer is to convert the input raster to signed integer and then run it.

The raster type likely cannot hold negative values.

Run gdalinfo on AestheticMax.tif and you will likely find it is 8-bit integer.

**From your link**

In fact, the r.reclass program ***does not generate any new raster map layers*** (in the interests of disk space conservation). Instead, a reclass table is stored which will be used to reclassify the original raster map layer each time the new (reclassed) map name is requested. As far as the user (and programmer) is concerned, that raster map has been created.

Comment: I changed -1 to 1000000. After re-reading the documentation I am even more confused. The documentation also says: "r.reclass creates an output map layer". If r.reclass creates reclass table, where is it? How do I use it? Could you provide an example?

Comment: well that would not be valid either, if you want to trouble shoot just run your code but with one change for me 35 = 99 and nothing else. No other items in the reclass text aside from 35 = 99

Comment: Why is this not valid?  1000000 is a signed integer. Ok, I did what you suggested. My 'reclass.txt' file is now just "35 = 99". I get the same result. The script runs, there is no output. I am expecting an output to my 'rules_file' variable, which is a path to where my output is saving.

Comment: @ErichPurpur Because it is over 255!

Comment: @ErichPurpur so not output file at all? If so do the 35 =99 thing again but put the input raster and the output path in C:\temp.

Comment: Nothing happens. I think I will give up on this tool and use SAGA reclassify values. I clearly don't know what I'm doing in GRASS.  Thanks for trying!